# How can I modify my db for a Logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I have the following fields in my database:

- record: row number
- Father: (1 to 7 values)
- Mother: (1 to 7 values)
- Age: 13, 14, 15 and 16 yo.
- Gender: Male/Female
- Suicide: (1/0 values)

I'd like to create a ggplot from this logistic regression model where my response variable is Suicide vs Parent's education (Father & Mother)
The plot has a straight line and not a curve as I expect, I'm using this code:

```
ggplot( baseRL, aes(x=Father, y=Suicide)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data = baseRL, aes(x = Father, y = Suicide),
              method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
              se = FALSE)
```

Is there another way to plot my objective?
Thanks!

Comment: Impossible to say without a [mcve] but: my guess is that you're plotting over a range where the logistic curve is close to linear (predicted probabilities in the range 0.3-0.7). If you extend the range of the x-axis (even if the values don't make sense, e.g. -5 to 13) and use `fullrange=TRUE` in `geom_smooth()`, you might see something.  (Or it might be something else entirely.)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080625/plotting-predictions-from-a-logistic-regression/47081221#47081221